# Changing an Application's icon from the terminal OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, icons

So I have an application that I'd like to change the icon for. If I drag and drop the new icon into the  app's `Contents/Resources/` via the GUI, the app updates ok.

However, if I `cp` the icon in the terminal the icon doesn't update, and the original icon is still displayed or a slightly broken version of the original is shown.

What else do I need to do to allow the .icns to be updated via the terminal (I need to be able to script this for a project.)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little late perhaps but take a look at this [article](https://www.sethvargo.com/replace-icons-osx).

Seth Vargo explains how he created a folder with his custom icons at `~/.custom-icons` and a little script that he runs every time an app update resets its icon.

```
function replace_icons() {
  cp ~/.custom-icons/atom.icns /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/atom.icns
  touch /Applications/Atom.app
  sudo killall Finder && sudo killall Finder
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check two things:

1. Make sure that `filename.icns` is the exact filename referenced in `Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources` and `Contents/PkgInfo`
2. Make sure that the permissions for `filename.icns` are correct.  If you run `ls -l` from within `Contents/Resources/`, you should see that `filename.icns` has the owner `root` and the group `wheel`, with permissions listed as `-rw-r--r--`.  If you do not see that, the commands you'll need to run to fix this are:

   `sudo chown root:wheel filename.icns`

   `sudo chmod 644 filename.icns`

If you'd like a little more info on permissions check out the following links:

http://www.macinstruct.com/node/415  (helpful guide on permissions and ownership)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/chown.8.html (chown manual)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/chmod.1.html (chmod manual)

Comment: Unfortunately that's already the case with the permissions / access modes correct, when the file is copied via the shell. BTW, user ownership permissions don't come into play with the drag-drop method. The owner was listed as *username*:admin